# Is there a search engine for looking up a pantone color by company that owns it

Tags: search, ads

I know some pantone colors are registered to particular companies. For example there is a specific pantone for Tiffany Blue (1837). Pantone.com seems to let you search by code, but is there a site that I can type "IBM Blue" or "Tiffany Blue" and get the pantone code for?

To clarify my specific needs, I work for an ad firm as a developer. It would be convenient to be able to look up the registered pantone colors of my clients when I don't have access to them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an [insane PDF here](http://www.copat.de/markenformen/Farbmarken2007.pdf) apparently listing every known color trademark.

Trademarks are vague things... they're not like domain names, where it's very clear who owns which one. The intent of trademark law is that competitors are not permitted to do things which might reasonably cause confusion as to the origin of a product. So, for example, a jewelry store that opened up across the street from Tiffany and used powder-blue boxes might get in trouble, even if they used a slightly different color, but a camera company could use the exact same color as Tiffany in their logo and packaging and possibly get away with it because they are in a different business and reasonable people would not be confused into thinking the cameras came from Tiffany.

Comment: Joel, thanks for the PDF. Its kind of hard to search since it seems to be in German. However, its a start.

Answer (score 0):

As a designer (when doing a task for the company being a partner, etc), a way I have is to search for "press kit", or their design/logo guidelines pdf or whatever the document. If they only provide a correct eps file, you might know from there (opening in Photoshop/Illustrator/Freehand maybe even Scribus.) which pantone their trademark elements are using, but often, in the section of the site dedicated to it, they describe in detail which pantones are used in their logo, etc. Often it's located in "Media", "Press", "About" or "Resources" sections.